# Are there any open-source Direct X code-bases that I can look at to learn from as a beginning Direct X and graphics programming student?

Tags: directx, directx11

I'm a third-year university student and I've recently begun studying Direct X 11. Mostly I've been following the samples from the SDK and reading a lot out of the MSDN. Although I have a decent conceptualization of the pipeline in general, I have no exposure to how various steps are broken down organizationally in an actual large production code-base. I understand that finding an open-sourced Direct X code-base, preferably version 11, is probably a lot to ask, considering it's only supported on a closed-source platform, but I was hoping I might get lucky.

Cheers,
Joseph

Comment: This kind of question is not appropriate for this website. In general, any question that just asks for links to something is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of open source rendering engines that implement direct3d as part of their pipeline. Whether or not it is directx 11 isn't terrible significant, as the rendering architecture overall is what is important, not the specific API calls. Irrlicht and Ogre are just a couple of the rendering engines you can look at. The API is insignificant from a learning perspective, in fact, you may get more out of it by referencing an implementation that uses one API, while actually writing your own using an alternate.